# Recommendation for compact lighting that I can hang or clamp on a door?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, lighting

I'm looking for recommendations for a small (LED?) light that I can temporarily hang or clamp on a door, e.g. in a bedroom, for whenever I need to take photos indoors (and then easily unplug it and store it away).  I just need something basic, ideally not more than few inches in diameter, and cheap.

Comment: Photos indoors with a cheap led light? That light is potentially a very, very bad lighting.

Answer (score 1):

You want an off camera flash and a clamp mount.  If you want something that can be small (particularly with the cheap requirement), then you are not looking at continuous lighting options.  They are much larger and more expensive to get good brightness and light quality, particularly if you want something LED driven.

There are a large selection of off camera flashes available cheaply though and can be used with a variety of clamp based solutions that will allow easy mounting to a door or anything you can fit the clamp around.  As an added benefit, these are also battery powered so you could just clip them and go.

Comment: Thanks, @AJ.  How do you control when the flash fires, though?

Comment: @A.Ro depends on the flash system you use.  There are wired and wireless options and wireless options can be both optical or RF based.  Either way, your camera actually controls setting them off, either by a cable, setting off a flash attached to it or using a radio transmitter (either built in or on the hotshoe) to tell the other flashes to fire.  If you don't have a camera with a hotshoe, I believe there are also flashes that will go off when they detect another flash.

Comment: Got it, @AJ.  What about when I'm using my iPhone to shoot and want to avoid using the iPhone flash?

Comment: @A.Ro You get what you pay for.  I highly suspect that the cost of getting something that would meet your requirements of good quality light and clip on to a door will make it cheaper to switch cameras than to try using your iPhone.